# What Qt widgets I need to use the read-only, scrollable, item list (pyqt4)

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt4, qwidget

What is the best QWidget to use as such a list as in the picture.

[image: call history]

- item =  image, two texts in vertical position and other text on right
  align.
- the list will be have not many items, an average of 50-100 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom form class that displays one list item. Use QLabel widgets to display texts and images.

You can add all item widgets to a `QVBoxLayout` and put it in a `QScrollArea`. Altenatively, you can use `QListWidget` and put item widgets in it using `QListWidget::setItemWidget`. I think the second approach will be more convenient.

Comment: I rule out the use of a simple widget, because the program is gaining a lot of RAM and using QListWidget NO! I will try to using QListWidget::setItemWidget. Thanks(спасибо) Pavel

Comment: I think, delegates are more prefferable. Ofc, it require more code, but it will have much better performance. But for 50-100 items widgets are OK.